# Generating grammar which contains all the alphabets

Tags: automation, context-free-grammar, automata, context-free-language, computer-science-theory

I need to construct a CFG for the language which can generate any phrase containing all symbols.

```
S -> ABC
A -> a,b,c,d.........z | B
B -> .,?,-,=,.... | C
C -> A | epsilon
```

I think it's not right. is there anyway to make it work so it can generate any phrase?

Answer (score 0):

i just figured it with my friend. here is the answer

```
S -> ABC | A | B
A -> aS,bS,cS,dS.........zS | B
B -> .S,?S,-S,=,.... | C
C -> A | epsilon
```